# Apps cannot be installed

Tags: software-installation

Every time I try installing the app `sublime-text`, it shows that the app is installing, but after sometime it shows this message:

[image: screenshot]

When I opened another terminal I can see that the app is not installed. I also cannot close that message by clicking OK.

This error started when I was trying to install sublime-text
Here are the commands I used:

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Comment: You can't click things in a terminal - you need to use the arrow keys so that the "_<OK>_" text is active, and then press enter.

Comment: @JonasCz Not entirely true, you can click items in terminal with certain programs like `htop`, even over SSH.

Comment: Why dont you accept the license for the fonts?

Comment: @Pilot6 He was trying to click on the `<Ok>` with the mouse which is why it didn't work.  These basic menus need keyboard input to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain terminal programs that create their interface with `ncurses` for example, will accept mouse input.  An example is `htop` where you can click the column titles to sort them, even over an SSH session.

Most menus however require keyboard navigation by either pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> or use the arrow keys to navigate and highlight the different options.  To select a highlighted option you can press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd>.

EDIT: I'm sure there are other libraries other than `ncurses` that allow this GUI behaviour, but that's the only one I know/use.